React DatePicker not getting closed after the date selection
I am trying to use react-hook-form with react-datepicker. I am using a button to open the datepicker, and trying to close it once the selection of a new date is made.

Below is the code-sandbox I made showing the exact problem I am facing.
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/react-datepicker-qwfyfs?file=%2Fsrc%2FDatePicker.jsx%3A105%2C33
The control is not even going to the onChange in the DatePicker component while trying to debug. The DatePicker component can only be closed by clicking again on the button.
Any help is much appreciated

sandbox not found

Sorry about that, heres the working link. Sandboxes are drafts by default now, didn't know :)
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/react-datepicker-qwfyfs?file=%2Fsrc%2FDatePicker.jsx%3A105%2C33

Your {...props} seems to overwrite the onChange logic. So you can remove the {...props} if not needed or if it does then put it first so that it does not overwrite the rest logic.
          <DatePicker
            {...props}
            inline
            selected={selected}
            onChange={(date) => {
              console.log("event");
              try {
                handleChange(date);
              } catch (err) {
                console.log("error :", err);
              } finally {
                setIsOpen(false);
              }
            }}
            calendarStartDay={1}
          />


Thanks man, how did I miss it
